# The VBScript below cannot open .cmd file. How can I make it work?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, vbscript

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\Testing.cmd" & Chr(34), 0
```

The above VBScript cannot open the following D:\Testing.cmd. Can anyone help?

```
@echo %date% %time%
pause
```

Comment: Is the cmd extension assigned to anything?  Windows is trying to use the best program it can to open the file but if cmd has no "open using this program" set, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "C:\tmp\Testing.cmd", 1, True
```

Read the documentation for "Run": http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

The point is, you've used the flag "0" that means "hide the window".

> 0 - Hide the window (and activate another window.)
>
> 1 - Activate and
>   display the window. (restore size and position) Specify this flag when
>   displaying a window for the first time.